# How to assign a string's initial character and the last character to a pointer of type unsigned char const?

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Str {"Stackoverflow"};
    unsigned char const *Ptr = &Str.front();
    unsigned char const *BufLim = &Str.back();

    cout<<ptr;
    cout<<BufLim;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is not compiling, I'm getting:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, char>::value_type*’ {aka ‘char*’} to ‘const unsigned char*’

I want to assign a string's initial character and the last character to a pointer of type `unsigned char const`.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: @churill Ouch! You're correct. My fault! (What a shame.) (I could swear I've seen `char * const`... Maybe, I need new glasses.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yep, it's quite easy to confuse this pointer madness, no reason to bea ashamed. :)

Comment: You could trust `auto`